# Jboss as maven plugin remote deployment issue

Tags: java, maven, deployment, jboss

I am trying to deploy a war file from a unix box to another unix box where the jboss eap is running using the below goals

mvn clean install jboss-as:deploy

Deployment works fine for some projects with small war size. But fails for projects with war sizes aroung 40MB with below error

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.3.Final:deploy (default-cli) @  ---
INFO: XNIO Version 3.0.7.GA
Jun 13, 2014 6:35:49 AM org.xnio.nio.NioXnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.7.GA
Jun 13, 2014 6:35:49 AM org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl <clinit>
INFO: JBoss Remoting version 3.2.12.GA
Authenticating against security realm: ManagementRealm
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 59.685s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Jun 13 06:36:28 GMT+00:00 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 41M/996M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jboss.as.plugins:jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.3.Final:deploy      

    (default-cli) on project: Deployment failed and was rolled back. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

Can someone help?

Comment: run build with `-e -X` and paste the error log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The deployment scanner has a default timeout setting of 60 seconds. This means that if your deployment does not complete within a minute, it will be canceled.

More information can be found [here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Deployment+Scanner+configuration), but in essence, you need to change the timeout setting in your `standalone.xml` or `domain.xml` configuration file.

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:1.1">
    <deployment-scanner path="deployments" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir"
        scan-interval="5000" deployment-timeout="300" />
    <!-- sets the timeout to 5 minutes -->
</subsystem>
```

Comment: When i check standalone-ha.xml, i can see scan-interval="5000" deployment-timeout="1800" means the timeout is 30mins rite?

Comment: I tried running with -X and -e, and got the below exception          Caused by: org.jboss.as.plugin.common.DeploymentExecutionException: Deployment failed and was rolled back.

Comment: I couldn get any information from the server log. The war size is 41MB. Also, I am able to deploy the generated war using admin console without any issues.

Comment: You have a failed deployment. The reason for this failure is in the log. Without the log, we don't have a lot of information go on.

Comment: I will try checking the server.log

Comment: And there you have your answer.

Comment: 17:55:14,710 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/My-Project]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 1208) JBWEB000284: Exception starting filter

Comment: Yeah, so investigate the issue, or create a new question about your deployment exception with more complete log output.